# McNemar's test implementation in Java

Tags: java

Does any body know of a Java implementation of McNemar's Test?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know such a library, but the statistics part of the [apache commons math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html) (written in java) provides a series of distributions, including chi2. Since the McNemar's Test does not seem to be thaaat complicated, you may figure an implementation out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Mcnemar+test+java):
http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/contingencytables/McNemarTest.html
Does it do anything for you? McNemar's Test is implemented in the Java Statistical Classes Library, specifically in [jsc.contingencytables](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/contingencytables/package-summary.html).

Comment: (+1): Unfortunately this seems to be an orphaned project.